# Density Estimation with R

Tags: r

With this code is possible to calculate the density.
Nevertheless, the result is not good because I don't want a plot like the one at stake, but, I would get a "continuous" line.

```
J = 512
Y = faithful$waiting
y = seq (min(faithful$waiting),+ max(faithful$waiting), length= J)

h = 5
n = length(Y)
d = rep(NA, J)

for(j in 1:J) {
  I = ifelse(y[j] - h < Y & Y <= y[j] + h, 1, 0)
  d[j] = sum(I)/(2*h*n)

}
n
plot(y, d, type = "l")
```

How I can get a "continuous line" like the attachment

Comment: You didn't add an attachment; I'd guess that's because you're a new contributor and SO wouldn't let you.

Comment: If you want a smooth estimator, you need to use a different method of density estimation, e.g. kernel density estimation.  The `stats::density()` function does this; if you want to do it yourself, replace your formula for `I` with something like `dnorm(y[j] - Y, sd = h)`.

Comment: You are calculating many repeated values thus the graph looking like a stair steps.  The range in faithful$waiting from 43 to 96, if you decrease J from 512 to 53 the graph looks much better.